# get rid of space between img lines

Tags: html, css

how can I get rid of the space horizontally and vertically between squares?

```
<div class="first">

  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/111111/000000.jpg"/></li>

    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/222222/000000.jpg"/></li>

    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/333333/000000.jpg"/></li>

    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/444444/000000.jpg"/></li>
  </ul>
</div>  
<div class="first">

  <ul>
    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/555555/000000.jpg"/></li>

    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/666666/000000.jpg"/></li>

    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/777777/000000.jpg"/></li>

    <li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/40x40/888888/000000.jpg"/></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ruyer/x61h9s4a/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `font-size:0;` for parent when you giving `display:inline-block;` for child.

```
.first ul{
  font-size: 0;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nikhilvkd/x61h9s4a/2/

Comment: This is a hidden css trick ;)